# CSS GRID column or row that overrides JS

Tags: javascript, css-grid

I'm not actually sure my title is correct.

I have this JS code that generates images from a directory.

In this code I want to add several images from other directory but give them specific places in my css grid.
The JS overrides this because of being launched after the css script.
I tried adding !important and inline css but nothing changes.

*EDIT: specifically adds a grid row or column place.
As in class "21" should place the img in column 2 row 1 and always be there.*

js code :

```
<script async defer>
        var imagePath = "./img/seperate-";
        var numberOfImage = 208;

        var parentDIV = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-container-parent")[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfImage; i++) {
            var tempDIV = document.createElement('div');
            tempDIV.setAttribute('class', 'grid-container-parent', 'test');
            var innerHTML = `<img src='` + (imagePath + i) + `.png'></img>`
            tempDIV.innerHTML = innerHTML;
            parentDIV.appendChild(tempDIV);
        }
    </script>
```

html:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-container-parent">
        <img class="other img" href="img2/other.img">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(90px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr));
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container-parent img {
    display: grid;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    height: 115px;
    width: 98.44px;
    object-fit: cover;
    float: left;
    grid-column: auto;
}

.other {
    display: grid;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    height: 115px;
    width: 98.44px;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-column: 22 !important;
    grid-row: 4 !important;
}
```

Comment: just add css styles from java script after your images are appended

Comment: Primary reason why your CSS is not working is wrong class name in your HTML - 
you should remove the "dot" character from `.other` class name of the `<img>`. However, there are other potential problems in your code why this is not working.

Comment: @Hemangvora small example?

Comment: @83C10 I changed the error .other what are the others?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("classname").style.color = "red";

like this apply all styles

Comment: @Hemangvora which lang should I use to attach a grid.column and grid.row to that class? I updated the question. 
I did not know that css grid is not a basic style option for JS

Comment: you can try using css bootstrap framework which uses grid to divide your screen size into 12 parts and its easier to put your content into specific grid :-)